# ComboBox.FindControl("TextBox") returning NULL in IE11 but working on IE9

Tags: combobox, internet-explorer-11

This is an unanswered question in some blogs... `

[<< Please Click Here To This Unanswered Question In Other Blogs..>>](http://forums.asp.net/p/1957081/5585749.aspx?ComboBox%20FindControl%20TextBox%20returning%20NULL%20in%20IE11%20but%20working%20on%20IE9)

will greatfull if can..

am trying to retrive Combobox selected item into a TextBox..here is my code..

using AjaxControlToolKit.dll version - 4.5.7.1002 for ComboBox.

i need to run this code on IE11 for sure.

Please help me in getting solution.

~ Udai

Answer (score 0):

For the difference in html mentioned in reference,you need to access your control using clientId, on of the ways is:-

```
var TextBoxXXXID = <%=textBoxXXXID .ClientID%>
var control= document.getElementById(TextBoxXXXID);
```

About the issue this can be because of browser compatibility issue, you would like to add meta tag and add app_brower folder specified in the [link](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx) .

Answer (score 0):

IN IE 11, use this code to find user input in the textbox in the AjaxComboBox.
It is working in Chrome as well.

ASPX -

```
<ajaxToolkit:ComboBox ID="cboMetric" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:ComboBox>
```

Code behind -

```
TextBox textBox = cboMetric.FindControl("cboMetric_TextBox") as TextBox;
strMetric = textBox.Text;
```